# Functional components inside vs outside of React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am wondering what the effects of coupling / nesting a functional component inside a React class component without explicitly passing props to it via params and using `this.props` via the parent class are.  I understand that having a functional component outside of the React class component is easier to test and read, but am curious to know what the exact difference between using `this.props` vs `props` via params are in terms of performance / renders.

For example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  bar = () => { return (<p>{this.props.baz}</p>) }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
      {this.bar()}
    )
  }
}
```

Vs.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
      <Bar baz={'foobar'}
    )
  }
}
function Bar(props) {
  return <p>{props.baz}</p>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both give the same result except when you care about code reusability.

If you care about reusing the `Bar` function then you better keep it outside the `class` so you can `import` it elsewhere.

**Example:**

If `Bar` renders a `success` or `warning` message. you'll want to keep the same design for all warning messages in the system. 
Now if every `component` has its own warning message code, **you'll not be able to edit the warning message design easily also you'll have to keep rewriting the same code over and over again**.

Comment: I know results in terms of visuals will be the same, but I'm curious if say the name prop updates, but baz does not.  Will Bar re-render in both instances?

Comment: in this case by default yes it will re-render, but you can use `react memo` to tweak this behavior https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo
@tomato